# Why debug not working properly when working multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging

I have basic information about multithread programming so i efforted to improve this topic and working debug mode but it doesnt work properly.

Code Example:

```
public class MultiThreadsExample implements Runnable {

private Thread t;
private String threadName;
```

//I have constructor method creating thread

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiThreadsExample thread1=new MultiThreadsExample("Thread-1");
    thread1.start();
    MultiThreadsExample thread2=new MultiThreadsExample("Thread-2");
    thread2.start();

}
//runnable interface override method
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running thread name:" + threadName);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("Working thread: " + i + " " + threadName);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MultiThreadsExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " interrupted.");
}

public void start() {
    System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Thread(this, threadName);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

`Creating thread name:Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
Creating thread name:Thread-2
Starting Thread-2
Running thread name:Thread-1
Working thread: 0 Thread-1
Working thread: 1 Thread-1
Working thread: 2 Thread-1
Working thread: 3 Thread-1
Thread Thread-1 interrupted.
Running thread name:Thread-2
Working thread: 0 Thread-2
Working thread: 1 Thread-2
Working thread: 2 Thread-2
Working thread: 3 Thread-2
Thread Thread-2 interrupted.`

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: I want to it works synchronized on debug mode but works serial

Comment: The threads running serially is a possible and still-correct outcome. When you use threads, you give up a lot of control over when/how they run. If you want that control back, take a look at the stuff in `java.util.concurrent`.  (If you just want to see the working stuff interleaved, though, it might help to sleep significantly longer. I generally use 1 sec delays for examples like this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I suppose, you want to have an output like:

`Working thread: 0 Thread-1
Working thread: 0 Thread-2
Working thread: 1 Thread-1
Working thread: 1 Thread-2
...`

That's not how threads work. You can't control the order in which threads are executed exactly.
Its up to the JVM and depends highly on things like your machine and your OS and since you are debugging maybe even your IDE.
So as fare as i can tell your code works as it should.

By the way this is the output when i run your code so it works on my machine:

`Creating thread name: Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
Creating thread name: Thread-2
Starting Thread-2
Running thread name:Thread-1
Running thread name:Thread-2
Working thread: 0 Thread-1
Working thread: 0 Thread-2
Working thread: 1 Thread-1
Working thread: 1 Thread-2
Working thread: 2 Thread-1
Working thread: 2 Thread-2
Working thread: 3 Thread-1
Working thread: 3 Thread-2
Thread Thread-1 interrupted.
Thread Thread-2 interrupted.`

You should check out some tutorials on concurrency in java like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).
They explain some basics about thread synchronizazion.